# Composer does not fetch dependencies from local repository

Tags: php, composer-php

I am trying to add a local project A as dependency to project B. Using `git daemon` I am able to fetch project A as dependency, but the dependencies defined with `require` in the composer.json in project A are not recognized. What am I missing?

project A:

```
{
    "name": "project/a",
    "require": {
        "monolog/monolog": "dev-master"
    }
}
```

project B:

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "git://localhost/home/user/project-a"
    }
],
"require": {
    "project/a": "dev-master"
}
```

result (in project B):

```
vendor/
  project/a
```

expected:

```
vendor/
  project/a
  monolog/monolog
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The most likely explanation is that you forgot to commit the changes to your `composer.json` in `/home/user/project-a`.

To debug this you can use `composer show project-a dev-master -v`. The `-v` will output more verbose info while it loads the repository, and then you will see details about the version you are installing, if it does not contain the monolog require, then I would say my guess above was correct. If it does contain it, we got a serious bug in composer and you should report it on github.

Comment: I tried to reproduce the problem today, but somehow now it seems to work, although I haven't committed any changes to either repository since the last attempt. Maybe it was a weird caching problem? I will play around and see if it happens again... edit: I'm accepting your answer anyway, `composer show -v` helps  a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue and my issue was that I was running `composer update` instead of `composer install` and one of the libraries that I required defined some of its dependencies as zipballs from GitHub.